# How to check a radio button by clicking or typing into a textbox?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple example below. If you click on the text, it checks the radio button. When I click into the textbox I can see the radio button darken for a split second, but it does not get checked. Is there a simple method to check the radio button on clicking the textbox or typing into the textbox?

```
<label><div class='mi' id='r4'><input type='radio' name='tt2' value='4' id='radio_4'> TEST TEXT ONE</div></label>
<label><div class='mi' id='r5'><input type='radio' name='tt2' value='4' id='radio_4'> TEST TEXT TWO</div></label>
<br />
<label>
<div class='mi' id='r1' style="float:left;"><input type="radio" name="tt2" value="2" id="radio_2"> TEST TEXT THREE</div>
<div class='mi' id='r2' style="float:left;"><input type='text' name='tt2' size="3px"> TEST TEXT FOUR</div>
<div class='mi' id='r3' style="float:left;"><input type='text' name='tt2' size="3px"> TEST TEXT FIVE</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JS to check the radio when you click the text input.  Like this:

```js
function checkRadio(){
  
  document.getElementById('radio_2').checked = "true";
  
  }
```

```html
<label><div class='mi' id='r4'><input type='radio' name='tt2' value='4' id='radio_4'> TEST TEXT ONE</div></label>
<label><div class='mi' id='r5'><input type='radio' name='tt2' value='4' id='radio_4'> TEST TEXT TWO</div></label>
<br />
<label>
<div class='mi' id='r1' style="float:left;"><input type="radio" name="tt2" value="2" id="radio_2"> TEST TEXT THREE</div>
<div class='mi' id='r2' style="float:left;"><input type='text' name='tt2' onclick="checkRadio()" size="3px"> TEST TEXT FOUR</div>
<div class='mi' id='r3' style="float:left;"><input type='text' name='tt2' onclick="checkRadio()" size="3px"> TEST TEXT FIVE</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</label>
```

I tried to clean up your code, too.  It was a little confusing because of it's formatting.  You also had a lot of closing HTML tags, but no opening tags.  Hope this helps!